# opening multiple PDF in a frame

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

The requirement is that there are a couple of hyperlink on the left upon clicking the hyperlink I need to open PDF's on the right in a frame

(it can be a content editor or a page viewer etc.)

i placed two script editor (on the left and right, one to show hyperlinks another for the pdf).please see below for the code i have used

here i have loaded pdfs but hid all but the first one

```
<object class="pdfobject" id="1" data="https://he.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/PMMDetailsPDF/1.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=1" width="800" height="800" type="application/pdf" />
```

here i created hyperlinks pointing to the same page and Jquery to show the pdfs.

Pdf1 
Pdf1
Pdf1

$('.pdflink').click(function(){
    $('.pdfobject').hide(); //Hide all pdf
    var objId = $('this').attr('objectid'); //Get pdf object element id from link
    $('#' + objId).show(); //Show respective pdf
});

Answer (score 1):

There are know issues with dynamically changing the source file path. Workaround you can try is by hiding and showing respective frame on clicking the link.

You can use jQuery or pure JavaScript to do this.

Adding link to Script Editor webpart as below

```
<object class="pdfobject" id="1" .... /> --This will be visible initially
<object class="pdfobject" id="2" style="display:none;"...
<object class="pdfobject" id="3" style="display:none;"...
....
```

Now you can handle the link

```
<a href="..." class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a>
<a href="..." class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a>
<a href="..." class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a>
....
```

You can use below jQuery code

```
$('.pdflink').click(function(){
    $('.pdfobject').hide(); //Hide all pdf
    var objId = $('this').attr('objectid'); //Get pdf object element id from link
    $('#' + objId).show(); //Show respective pdf
});
```

Comment: so i have 20 pdf i can add all that using the method below and show or hide  using javascript ? . Here is what i have done i had added a script editor and add the below code to show the pdf <object width="800" height="800" type="application/pdf" data="https://mydomain.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/DetailsPDF/5.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=0"id="pdf_content">  . should i add others one in the same way and hide the rest of them using javascript ? . sorry to ask ,can you show me one example to do so.  I am not good with javascript

Comment: @Rinu how big are the PDF files? If you place 20 pdf the page will load slowly. Have you thought about adding 20 page and link it?

Comment: all the pdfs are less than 1 mb some as small as 64 kb. It needs to be shown in one page. at the movement i added all the pdfs in one document library and open it using a script editor using the above code. The requirement is to show the links/buttons on the left and upon clicking the respective pdf shows on the right.

Comment: sorry for beeing a bit ignorant and the delay . i have used the below code but it redirects and opens the pdf in the page itself

Comment: <a href="https://te.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/PMMDetailsPDF/1.pdf" class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a> <br>
<a href="https://te.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/PMMDetailsPDF/2.pdf" class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a><br>
<a href="https://te.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/PMMDetailsPDF/3.pdf" class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a><br>

<script>
$('.pdflink').click(function(){
    $('.pdfobject').hide(); //Hide all pdf
    var objId = $('this').attr('objectid'); //Get pdf object element id from link
    $('#' + objId).show(); //Show respective pdf
});
</script>

Comment: in the script editor i have added the below as advised <object class="pdfobject" id="1" data="https://te.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/PMMDetailsPDF/1.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=1" width="800" height="800" type="application/pdf" /> 
<object class="pdfobject" id="2" style="display:none;" data="https://te.sharepoint.com/sites/SiteOffices/PMMDetailsPDF/2.pdf?#zoom=85&scrollbar=1&toolbar=0&navpanes=1" width="800" height="800" type="application/pdf" />

Comment: All the a tag href should be # and not the actual links

Comment: done it in a script editor with the code below but the jquery is not firing  <a href=" #" class="pdflink" objectid="1">Pdf1</a> <br>
<a href=" #" class="pdflink" objectid="2">Pdf1</a><br>
<a href=" #" class="pdflink" objectid="3">Pdf1</a><br>
<script>
$('.pdflink').click(function(){
    $('.pdfobject').hide(); //Hide all pdf
    var objId = $('this').attr('objectid'); //Get pdf object element id from link
    $('#' + objId).show(); //Show respective pdf
});
</script>